# RavenDb Smuggler error during multiple exports

Tags: c#, database, ravendb, invalidoperationexception, processstartinfo

I'm using C# to launch multiple process (ProcessStartInfo) which execute the Raven.Smuggler.exe (all at the same time). This is probably a bad practise (which I am changing soon). However I would like to know if the action of launching muliple exports is causing the following error which occurs intermittently:

System.InvalidOperationException: The database {name} is currently being loaded, but after 30 seconds, this request has been aborted. Please try again later, database loading continues.

And this happens to over 50% of the exports while the rest succeed. So is the act of multiple export causing this error?

Comment: are you exporting to the same database?

Comment: No they are all different databases. I am exporting all 20 databases.